# search any continuous string in a column

Tags: sql

I have a scenario where i have to find the matching string from a table.

i used a self join query using substr and length to compare the strings.

Database is Teradata.

```
SELECT T1.*,T2.*
FROM TABLE T1,TABLE T2
WHERE
 T1.ID= T2.ID
 AND T1.DATE= T2.DATE
 AND T1.SYSTEM = 'ORCL'
 AND T2.SYSTEM = 'TER'
 AND SUBSTR(T1.NAME,1,5) = SUBSTR(T2.NAME,1,5);


TABLE 

  ID     DATE     NAME     SYSTEM
  1      SYSDATE  TEST     ORCL
  1      SYSDATE  @# TEST  TER
```

OUTPUT:

```
  ID    DATE     NAME   SYSTEM    ID_1  DATE_1      NAME_1    SYSTEM_!
  1     SYSDATE  TEST   ORCL       1     SYSDATE   '@#TEST'     TER
```

when im using substr 1 to 5 iam not getting accurate results as i get white spaces,special characters and and reversible names.

I need a query that will handle any situation to compare the string in a column.

Comment: If the name is not the same how do you want to compare it? what is considered "the same" and what is not? you'll have to come up with a tight definition/requirement in order to clarify your question.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: What is a "reversible name" generally one would solve this by using the levenshtein distance function (many folks have written implementation of that algorithm in tsql). But that's going to give you false positives and will require some tweaking on how "close" is acceptable. It's also going to be slow to perform on a join of large data. The real issue is that you are trying to join on bad data.

Comment: records for name column  need not to be same it can be similar , as shown in the example Test  for ORCL and TEST @# for TER are similar for the same id. So the names are identical for the same ID .